# JAVA Executable Jar can not start on deployment system but can satrt on development system

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I create this executable jar file using MArs Eclips and build it with option 1 "extract all requirement libraries to jar file".  This Jar file can start by double click on development system.  But when I copy to other system It can not start, I think because it can not find main class, when i ran it with
JAVAW it does not show anything, but when i ran it with JAVA it show class not found.

```
C:\HFU>java HomeForYou.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class HomeForYou.jar

C:\HFU>javaw HomeForYou.jar

C:\HFU>
```

I can not figure out what is an issues with it.

I has a rar file here for https://www.dropbox.com/s/7e4c479ugsoydq0/HFU.rar?dl=0

Development system has WIN & 64 bits,  MARS Eclip - JDK and JRE verion 8
Deployment system has WIN 7 64 bits JRE version 8

the class contains main is HomeForYouMain.class.

Comment: The correct command is `java -jar HomeForYou.jar`.

Comment: Thanks , I find out what is an issue with it.